# Ubuntu bash command find -exec

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, bash, find

I want to list every file that ends with "conf", and output the results to a given file (with the command *`find -exec`*).

I tried this:

```
find -name *conf -exec /home/ubuntu/myfile
```

Is this wrong?

Answer (score 10):

`-exec` is used for running a program, not printing the output.  Use `-print` to print the output, and shell redirection (`>`) to store that output in a file:

`find -name \*conf -print > /home/ubuntu/myfile`

Note that I escaped the `*` with a backslash; this is because the shell will attempt to match the wildcard before starting `find`, so if you happened to have a file that ended in `conf` in the current directory, the shell would replace `*conf` with that filename (or names) before starting `find`.

Answer (score 5):

```
find /path -type f -iname "*.conf" > /home/ubuntu/myfile
```